# Input Impeding in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to perform a search by input, which tries to display elements which have data matched with the input data. Here is the code:

```
var webUserdataTempInput = $(".Input").val();
$(".Input").keyup(function(e){

    if($(this).val()==webUserdataTempInput)
        return;
        webUserdataTempInput=$(".Input").val();
        var webUserdataCurrentNo=0,webUserdataCurrentPrio;
        for (webCount=0;webCount<$(".E").length;webCount++){
            if($(".webAdminUserdataInput").val()!=webUserdataTempInput)
                break;
            if($(".Input").val().length==0){
                $(".E").css("display","block");
                return;
            }
            var wI = $(".Input").val().toLowerCase();
            var wC = $(".E:eq("+webCount+")").attr("data-c").toLowerCase();
            var wE = $(".E:eq("+webCount+")").attr("data-e").toLowerCase();
            var wS = $(".E:eq("+webCount+")").attr("data-s").toLowerCase();
            var wU = $(".E:eq("+webCount+")").attr("data-u").toLowerCase();
            if(wC.replace(wI,"")==wC && wE.replace(wI,"")==wE && wS.replace(wI,"")==wS && wU.replace(wI,"")==wU){
                $(".E:eq("+webCount+")").css("display","none");
                $(".E:eq("+webCount+")").css("color","#fff");
            }else{
                $(".E:eq("+webCount+")").css("display","block");
                $(".E:eq("+webCount+")").css("color","#ff0");
                webUserdataCurrentNo++;
                webUserdataCurrentPrio=webCount;
            }
        }
});
```

This code works in both desktop and mobile versions, yet will become apparently slow when I use mobile phones to input that the character pops up after seconds. How can I force the browser to display the input character first and then the execution in order not to impede my mobile devices?

Comment: My solution to this has always been to introduce a timeout of a very short time, something like 1/5th of a second, and clear it any time a keydown event occurs, this way typing doesn't cause a delay, but once you stop typing it updates suddenly. Does this sound like the sort of thing that would work for you?

Comment: Can I set the timeout to be 1/10th of a second? I have done something   like this yet failed and I want the search result to be displayed as soon as possible.

Comment: See this [really simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N8x8P/), adjust the timeout as you see fit. - Worth noting that it may be a good idea to increase this timeout on mobile browsers by default to reduce the possible lag.

Comment: Your code succeed because there is only one command! However, in my code there are for loops which will be executed for somehow more than 100 times which makes things slow. Seems that setting timeout does not help with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the multiple parsings of ".E" is killing your app in a mobile environment.  If you could reduce the scope if possible, or store the list of ".E" elements in a variable, and use:

```
var elist = $(".E");
.
.
$elist.find(":eq(" + webCount + ")").css({ display: "block", color: "#ff0" });
```

Try reducing the scope of the checks if possible, and that will help aid your performance.  So a timeout will help, but it won't solve the underlying problem that DOM access and larger DOM trees will slow down an application in mobile.

Comment: Is there any useful algorithms that you may provide in order to reduce the scope of the checks?

Comment: Be as specific as possible.
`$("td.E");` or `$("div.E, span.E, li.E");` is faster then `$(".E");`

Comment: Or wrap the collection of E elements with a parent element as `$("#parentelementbyID").find(".E")`, because parent elements reduce the scope.  Or consider document fragments if possible (http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/).